# Grade 12 Calculus and Vectors Math Problem

Tags: vectors

Question: A plane has $-4y + 6z - 4 = 0$ as its Cartesian equation. Determine the Cartesian equation of a plane that is perpendicular to and contain the point $P(-3, -10, 4)$.

I tried doing this question on my own but I messed up and I don't understand how I'm supposed to find the answer to this question. To solve the question, I tried to use the cross product but I got even more confused when doing it. Am I supposed to use the cross product? Or do I use another method? i would appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Comment: If a plane is $n.(x,y,z)^T+d=0$ then $n$ is the plane normal vector, it's perpendicular to the plane. If you cross product the vector with an arbitrary vector $a$: $[n\times a]$ -- the resulting vector $n_1$ should work as the normal vector of the new plane (why?) and you can get the plane equation in the form $n_1.((x,y,z)^T-P)=0$

Comment: Start by choosing a suitable equation for a plane, one that lends itself to the key words “perpendicular” and “contain the point”.... Anything ring a bell? Also, how can we get a normal for a plane just by reading its equation? That’s a skill you should keep in your toolbox.

Comment: Do you recognize that there’s not a unique solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take $y=0$ or $1$ and then you can get two position vector. Then the direction of the plane can be found by using cross product of the two direction you had obtained.